# how to find the same two-digit numbers in a sequence of characters regular expressions SQL

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I would like to print out strings of characters in which at least two numbers are repeated in SQL

```
EX

11-22-33
11-22-44
22-22-33
55-22-33
11-66-33
11-88-33
33-88-33
77-77-22
```

OUTPUT :

```
22-22-33
77-77-22
33-88-33
```

But I have no idea how to write a regular expression that would help me

Comment: `col like '%11%' or col like '%22%' or ...` Does your platform actually support regular expressions? If so maybe this would work: `([0-9])\1`

Comment: ([0-9])\1 write everything, col like '%11%' or col like '%22%' I can't use it, because I don't know all the repeated combinations

Comment: I didn't see the output section earlier and thought we were dealing with just pairs of the same digit. Wouldn't `([0-9][0-9]).*\1` work?

Answer (score 2):

For this fixed format of `NN-NN-NN`, you could just use string functions and test the three possible combinations:

```
select *
from mytable
where substr(val, 1, 2) = substr(val, 3, 2) 
   or substr(val, 1, 2) = substr(val, 5, 2) 
   or substr(val, 3, 2) = substr(val, 5, 2)
```

We could get a little fancy and use a lateral join instead of the repeating `or` conditions. This scales better if you have more than 3 parts (the number of combinations increases rapidly, which makes the `or` solution less convinient):

```
select t.*
from mytable t
cross apply (
    select count(distinct part) cnt_distinct_part
    from (
        select substr(t.val, 1, 2) part
        union all select substr(t.val, 3, 2)
        union all select substr(t.val, 5, 2)
    ) x
) x
where x.cnt_distinct_part < 3
```

Comment: I think this is a clever approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular expression `(^|-)(\d+)(-\d+)*-\2(-|$)` to match pairs of numbers of any number of digits or number of terms.

- `(^|-)` matches either the start-of-the-string `^` or a hyphen `-` contained in the first capturing group `()`;
- followed by one-or-more digit characters `\d+` contained in the second capturing group `()` to match the first of the pair of the numbers;
- then a third capturing group `()` which is matched zero-or-more times `*` containing a `-` followed by one-or-more digits `\d+` to match any amount of numbers between the pair of matched numbers;
- then a hyphen `-`;
- then a duplicate of the second capturing group `\2` which will match the second of the pair of numbers;
- then either a hyphen `-` or the end-of-the-string `$`

Giving the query:

```sql
SELECT value
FROM   table_name
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( value, '(^|-)(\d+)(-\d+)?-\2(-|$)' );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT '11-22-33' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '11-22-44' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '22-22-33' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '55-22-33' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '11-66-33' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '11-88-33' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '33-88-33' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '77-77-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '11-77-77' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '11-177-77' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '11-77-771' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123-456-123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1-2-2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '99999-99999-0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-11-2-13' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | VALUE                       |
> | :-------------------------- |
> | 22-22-33                    |
> | 33-88-33                    |
> | 77-77-22                    |
> | 11-77-77                    |
> | 123-456-123                 |
> | 1-2-2                       |
> | 99999-99999-0               |
> | 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-11-2-13 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=171209670d2816b3eb4910acb448302c)*

Comment: Could you  explain this regular expression ?